# Connection Builder error

Tags: c#

I am trying to use connection builder so that I can put a path variable in it which will store the path of the directory the access database file is stored in. I am getting an error saying "Keyword not supported provider".

When I was just returning following (without the use of connection builder) it was working fine.

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Projects.accdb;
                                Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Please see what I am not doing correctly. I am new to c# by the way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DAL
{
    public class ConString
    {
        public string GetConString()
        {
            try
            {
                string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
                //string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Projects.accdb;
                 //               Persist Security Info=False;";
                OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder =
               new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(GetConnectionString());
                builder.ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
                builder.PersistSecurityInfo = false;
                builder.DataSource = path + "\\" + "Projects.accdb";

                return builder.ConnectionString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {

            return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Projects.accdb;" + 
                                "Persist Security Info=False;";


        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong connection string builder. You should use [OleDbConnecionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Because SqlConnectionStringBuilder is used for creating connections to MS SQL Server only.

Comment: Not quite sure how this is the answer considering the code sample showed he was already using `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: As I see question was edited after answer was accepted. I dont know why. Originally there was `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this change:

```
// builder.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
```

But, if you are starting with a valid connection string, the ONLY thing you should need to change is the DataSource.  If it's not working, I would suspect the connection string you are starting with is not valid.